# Setting the r attribute of an svg circle for an angular progress indicator

Tags: html, angular, svg

Reading [through some angular component code](https://github.com/crisbeto/angular-svg-round-progressbar/blob/master/src/round-progress.component.ts) code and the `r` attribute of an svg circle is set like this:

```
[attr.r]="radius - stroke / 2"
```

This works so I'm just trying to understand why?  IIUC the `r` attribute is the radius of the svg circle and so I'm curious why the component's radius attribute is not used directly?

Answer (score 0):

You can not to bind to `r`, because it is an *attribute*. Angular lets you to bind directly only *properties*, not attributes. So why you need to bind it via `[attr.r]`

Comment: It's not my code repository.  I'm just trying to understand the design.  This is the demo: http://crisbeto.github.io/angular-svg-round-progressbar/

Answer (score 0):

> attribute is the radius of the svg circle and so I'm curious why the component's radius attribute is not used directly?

The stroke in an SVG is drawn so that its centre follows the path.  So, for a circle, the stroke covers the region from `radius - stroke/2` to `radius + stroke/2`.

At a guess, I would say that the author wanted `radius` to correspond to the outside radius of the stroked circle.  So they subtracted half of the stroke width.  Meaning that now that the stroke covers the region from `radius - stroke` to `radius`.